# Pivote table having error

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table: **dbPratiche** having data as follows:

```
stato             Gruppi Min (GG Flusso/Decorrenza-->Out)

A1                      >10

A1                      >16

A2                      >06 

A3                      >08

A2                      >06

A2                      >08

A1                      >10

A3                      >06
```

I wanted to show data as:

```
Col       A1         A2          A3

>10       2          0           0

>16       1          0           0

>06       0          2           1

>08       0          1           1
```

For this i used pivote table logic

```
select * from 
(
select stato,[Gruppi Min (GG Flusso/Decorrenza-->Out)] 
from 
dbPratiche
) as tlb1
pivot
(
COUNT([Gruppi Min (GG Flusso/Decorrenza-->Out)] )
for [Gruppi Min (GG Flusso/Decorrenza-->Out)]
) pvt
```

But this is not giving me appropriate results.

Plz help me how can i obtain this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT [Gruppi Min (GG Flusso/Decorrenza-->Out)],SUM(CASE WHEN stato='A1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as A1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN stato='A2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as A2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN stato='A3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as A3
FROM table GROUP BY [Gruppi Min (GG Flusso/Decorrenza-->Out)]
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4cc0b/24)

Comment: sir, how can be the query if i want to select distinct(stato) at once for sum(case when....) becase if more data gets added to table this query will create problem

Comment: Why would you need distinct for stato?It just adds all up for the respective value,ie A1.If you mean add more values like a4,a5 by all means use pivot.

Comment: yup, i was talking abt a4,a5 but your query provided me exact result what i wanted...but fearing abt further additions to database table like a4,a5..coz m going to use this in reports

Comment: @LOLSinger You might be able to do it with dynamic sql,something like select all distinct values from stato and use them in the query on the fly,but this is above my pay grade.Ask a new question if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had not added in([]) within pivote thats why it was not working.

I made query as below:

```
select * from 
(
    select stato,[Gruppi Min (GG Flusso/Decorrenza-->Out)] 
    from 
    dbPratiche where
    Compagnia ='GENERALI INA ASSITALIA'
    and [Stato OUT/WIP] ='WIP'
)  tlb1
pivot
(
COUNT( [Gruppi Min (GG Flusso/Decorrenza-->Out)] )
for [Gruppi Min (GG Flusso/Decorrenza-->Out)] 

in([>10])

) PVT
```